# How to make the table cell content-text according to its width?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EncPS.png)

I have a attach a img in which my td content has two values first value is set as float left and second float right. It there any way to increase the width to make the cells contents on the same line and overflow to extend cell width.
Below is my code

```
   td,th{
        white-space: nowrap;
    width:auto;
    }


   .rightclass
    {
        float: right;
        white-space: nowrap;
    
    }



  .leftclass
    {
        border:3px solid red;
        border-top: 3px solid red;
         
        border-bottom: 3px solid red;
        
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    
    }


 <td align="right" class="redcolor"> <span class="leftclass">(9223333333333333333322225789)</span><span class="rightclass"> 12345</span></td>
```

Comment: Yes, you can increase the width of a special column/any column, but you cannot do it dynamically as the width of each column is being defined by the total contents in the table

Comment: If you want to display both in the same line independent of the content, you need to do some text-overflow techniques or you can use flex.